# Control solutions returned by DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

Is it possible to control which solutions Mathematica computes in `DSolve`? For example, the following differential equation:

```
DSolveValue[z u''[z] - (z + 2) u'[z] + u[z] == 0, u[z], z]
```

is solved as:

[image]

(Ouch!) when in fact this is a (complex) linear combination of the much simpler:

```
u1[x_]:= C[1] (2+x)
u2[x_]:= C[2] Exp[x](x-2)
```

Comment: Try to `FullSimplify` it.

Comment: Yes - `FullSimplify` almost works in this case, it shows the simpler expressions more directly. Is this a general recipe though?

Comment: `FullSimplify` often is helpful, but it does not always reduce solutions to the form that one might like.

Comment: The form returned by Mathematica probably reflects the resolution method used internally.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 DSolveValue[z u''[z] - (z + 2) u'[z] + u[z] == 0, u[z], z] // 
 FullSimplify[#, z > 0] &

(*  ((-1)^(1/4) (-E^z (-2 + z) (C[1] - I C[2]) - (2 + z) (C[1] + 
      I C[2])))/Sqrt[\[Pi]]  *)
```

Have fun!